# Issue with bootstrap and wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on making my first wordpress theme using Twitter Bootstrap. I am having a couple issues. The first issue is with the navigation links. If I hover directly over them, they don't highlight, I have to hover slightly underneath it. I have figured out the issue is related to `<?php wp_head(); ?>`. If I remove that line they function properly. My second issue is that whenever I hover over any part of the navbar, the content jumps down about 20px. You can check this out at http://www.mattaltepeter.com. I really have no clue how to fix my second problem. The first issue I have a workaround using padding-top, but I am curious as if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Browser? Looks good to me in chrome.

Comment: No problems here either. Ubuntu+Chrome.

Comment: no issue here in FF(WIN7), Mike is correct i think it's your Browser's problem...

Comment: @MikeCole hmm strange. I'm using OS X 10.8.3 and Safari 6.0.4. Tested it out in chrome and it worked fine. Not sure what could cause that issue in browsers that are very similar.

Comment: Oops. I figured it out. I had installed a plug-in that would hide the admin bar unless I hovered over it. I had used CSS to set the display property of the admin bar to none, but the function was still getting called, therefore messing everything up.

Comment: Tip: do not remove `wp_head`, it is an essential hook, used extensively by plugins (and even the WP core) to trigger all kinds of actions.